# Is Storm production ready?

Tags: python, storm-orm

Anybody using [Storm](https://storm.canonical.com/)? Is is stable enough to be used in production?

Comment: Ok, i'm confused. Isn't storm a Python ORM and isn't Twitter written in Ruby?

Comment: No No I am confusing you. :( I had mistaken it to "Twitter Storm" which is a Hadoop alternative. I am sorry.

Comment: "production-ready" is an overly vague umbrella term.

Comment: Question rightly closed. However Storm IS used for huge projects like launchpad for example. I prefer it over SQLalchemy as I find it to have a more minimalistic design, but again... it's a matter of preference and priorities, SQLalchemy could legitimately be considered a better choice by others.

Comment: I suggest you open a new question (using the correct tag) with a more accurate description of what you would like to know.